# Clear the terminal (but keep the last few lines)

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Suppose I've been in the terminal for a while, and it's length is very concerning (or equivalently a program that spits out a very long output).

Is there a way to keep the last 10 lines (for example), and clear the rest?

(Without scroll-back capability)

Comment: Do you want to erase scrollback history?

Comment: @muru Yes, I should clarify that

Comment: Which terminal are you using? GNOME Terminal clears scrollback history entirely with the `reset` command, but konsole doesn't. Neither seem to have an option to keep some of the history and erase the rest.

Comment: check out: man tput, tput cup 10 0 && tput ed

Comment: @muru Ah, I'm using GNOME

Comment: Edit $HISTFILE and choose lines you wanna purge.I use nano.

Comment: The `clear` command kinda accidentally does that, it clears the scrollback but preserves the last few lines. See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=771953 and https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=384218 for details what circumstances and workarounds lead to this weird situation. This might change in a future version, though. The escape sequence "\e[3J" on its own can be used to clear the scrollback.

Comment: What is "concerning" exactly, by the way? In profile prefs you can set the maximum number of lines to remember. In GNOME Terminal (and other VTE-based emulators) the lines that are scrolled out are compressed, encrypted and stored in an unlinked file in `/tmp`. As long as `df` reports enough free space under `/tmp`, there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> tput cup Y X
> ```
>
> Move cursor to screen location X,Y (top left is 0,0)
>
> ```
> tput ed
> ```
>
> clear to end of screen

So:

```
$ tput cup 10 0 && tput ed
```

[source](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html)

Comment: This doesn't clear scrollback history on GNOME Terminal, at least.